# Не запускается socket.io на node.js

Tags: node.js, сервер, vds, putty

При запуске выдает запись на скрине и на этом все, так и висит. Пробовал менять порт, пробовал исправлять что-то в коде, но это началось, когда я перенес сайт на другой сервер и домен так же перенаправил на другой ip. Код сервера опубликован ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    var PORT = 8008;

var options = {
//    'log level': 0
};
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : '****',
  user     : '****',
  password : '****',
  database : '****'
});
connection.connect();
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server, options);
server.listen(PORT);

app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/static'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
    client.on('message', function (message,id_my,id_you,id_you_book,komy) {
        try {   
            client.emit('message'+message.id_you, message);
            client.broadcast.emit('message'+message.id_you, message);
var post  = {my_id: message.id_my, you_id: message.id_you_book, text: message.text, book: message.id_you, komy: message.komy, type: 5, date: new Date()};
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO comment SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
console.log('Добавлен комментарий к книге');
});
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            client.disconnect();
            connection.end();
        }
    });
    client.on('stena', function (stena,id_my,id_you) {
        try {   
            client.emit('stena'+stena.id_you, stena);
            client.broadcast.emit('stena'+stena.id_you, stena);
var post  = {users2: stena.id_my, text: stena.text, users: stena.id_you, type: 3, date: new Date()};
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO repost SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
console.log('Добавлена запись на стену');
});
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            client.disconnect();
            connection.end();
        }
    });
        client.on('comment', function (comment,id_my,id_you,id_you_post,komy) {
        try {   
            client.emit('comment'+comment.id_you, comment);
            client.broadcast.emit('comment'+comment.id_you, comment);
var post  = {my_id: comment.id_my, you_id: comment.id_you_post, text: comment.text, post: comment.id_you, komy: comment.komy, type: 4, date: new Date()};
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO comment SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
console.log('Добавлен комментарий к записе');
});
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            client.disconnect();
            connection.end();
        }
    });
    client.on('art', function (art,id_my,id_you,id_you_art,komy) {
        try {   
            client.emit('art'+art.id_you, art);
            client.broadcast.emit('art'+art.id_you, art);
var post  = {my_id: art.id_my, you_id: art.id_you_art, text: art.text, art: art.id_you, komy: art.komy, type: 6, date: new Date()};
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO comment SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
console.log('Добавлен комментарий к арту');
});
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            client.disconnect();
            connection.end();
        }
    });
    client.on('chat', function (chat) {
        try {
            client.emit(chat.id, chat);
            client.broadcast.emit(chat.id, chat);
var post  = {dialog: chat.id, text: chat.text, users: chat.my, status: 1, date: new Date()};
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO chat SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
console.log('Добавлено сообщение');
});
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            client.disconnect();
            connection.end();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: использую digitalocean, проблем с запусками чего то на vds, тем более  ноды, не было. Если перестает подключатся к vds надо читать логи самой vds.

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Да, тоже хотел сначала туда. Но слышал что там с трафиком. Почитал в гугле, по любому это из-за порта, не подскажешь как открыть его на VDS-e?

Comment: А что такое `vds` если не секрет?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian выделенный приватный сервер)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев просто вы так о нем тут говорите, как будто это какой-то определенный провайдер.

Comment: @АльбертУшаков а в чем проблема попробовать на другом не стандартном порту? Да и вообще (по крайней мере на DO) порты не лочат, они могут лишь использоваться, НО, от этого сам ВДС не должен падать, это же линукс, он ругнется и все)

Comment: @VladimirGamalian это можно сказать выделенная для тебя персональная машина (компьютер), на которой ты можешь делать что тебе хочешь. Например поднять VPN для защиты и шифровки своей сети, любые приложения тестовые, сайты и т.д и т.п. Зачастую это выходит дешевле чем брать целенаправленный заказ типа, голосовой сервер TeamSpeak, когда на VDS ты можешь развернуть какой тебе надо в сколько угодно слотов, а заплатишь совсем скромные деньги

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев не, ну это то я понимаю, просто когда автор спрашивает как открыть на VDS, а потом ему digital ocean предлагается, создается ощущение, что VDS это тоже какой-то сервис, и на нем как-то по особенному порты открываются..

Comment: @VladimirGamalian ну ты если используешь роутер дома, порты пробрасываешь, чтобы дать доступ например к сайту какому нибудь у себя на компе, это тоже самое. Очень удобная вещь, если ты разработчик

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Хм, хотя странно порты не причем. Я ведь запускал на компе и при этом порты были закрыты. Добавил лог.

Comment: Что-то я в конец запутался. Пробую подключится через клиент, не идет. Порт использую 8081 ( Не стандартный ).

Comment: @АльбертУшаков ошибка того что порт уже занят. Ответ ниже успел раньше меня)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Я так и не нашел причины ошибки. Порт менял, открывал но похоже не то. Не запускается socket.

Comment: @АльбертУшаков у тебя сокет и http.server на одном порту запускаются, может в этом проблема?

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Я вот только что запустил этот же сервер на компе у себя и перенаправил клиент на него, все работает. Но на самом сервере почему то на него не подключается. Еще один вопрос, со стороны оптимизации, что если оставить так, node на одном сервере а сайт на другом, как думайте, это разбавит нагрузку на сервера? Ну и тогда mysql тоже на отдельный серв выставить?

Comment: сервер внутри своей среды работает быстрее, т.к. обращается к локальным данным (в облаке своих машин). Если что то будет находится на другой машине, других ДЦ запросы по времени вырастут в разы. Я на самом деле не знаю в чем у ещё может быть у вас проблема. У меня под линуксом на вдс все нормально запускается, не бывало проблем с косяками портов

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Значит я как то не так запускаю. Хотя вроде бы все так. Может подключение и ссылка должна быть другой? Вроде того, что директория не верна.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка на втором скрине - порт уже используется. NodeJS и firewall тут не причём. Убедитесь, что запуск Вашего же скрипта ранее не держит его открытым (перезагрузив VDS или посмотрев процессы `ps aux/kill -9 {id_неугодного}`)

Открыть порт извне, можно например так:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp  --dport 8008 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp  --dport 8008 -j ACCEPT
```

Командой `netstat -pan | grep 8008` убедится, что он открыт.
Должно быть : `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8008` если видите `127.0.0.1:8008` то указать в своём скрипте явно ip на котором он должен открываться: `0.0.0.0`

Comment: я бы только про перезагрузку VDS написал, что это нежелательная операция

Comment: @Etki нежелательная операция перезагрузка VDS? А какая причина?

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев дополнительное время и риски

Comment: @Etki своя VDS для личного пользования) Какие риски и время) По крайней мере моя ребутится в течении 13 секунд, бывает даже быстрее

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев будет весьма забавно, если вы пойдете перезапускать процесс, а вернетесь с незапускаемой VDS.

Comment: @Etki :D Вы дома и на работе никогда комп не выключаете? Это же дополнительно время и риски :D Вдруг при включении не загрузится :D Ржунимагу.

Comment: @MaxZS сервера у меня не выключаются никогда. С виртуалкой, которая не смогла дойти до загрузки ssh из-за прибитых системных файлов, сталкивался. Если никогда не спасали сервис в критической ситуации, то когда придется - не перезагружайте сервак.

Comment: @Etki Критические ситуации бывают. Но Ваш совет из разряда - никогда не летайте на самолетах, потому что их могут сбить террористы.

Comment: @MaxZS мой совет - не делать лишние операции там, где они не нужны, тем более радикального характера.

Comment: Перезагрузка не носит радикальный характер. Обычный рабочий момент, когда нужно переинициалировать систему и проверить всё ли подтягивается/запускается для рабочего режима так как нужно.  Серв который не может вернутся из перезагрузки - неработоспособен. Не следует маскировать это вечным аптаймом. Нужно решать эти проблемы.

Comment: @iosp  Извините, socket так и не запускается. Висит на started и все, пробовал по всякому, вообще не реагирует.

Comment: Запускаете задачу в фоне (добавив & в конец вашей строки запуска) затем пробуете соединится прямо из консоли. Думаю получится - потом решаете проблему с доступом из вне. Как правило настройками файрвола это решается.